# Executar um script python no redhat 7.4

Tags: python

Bom dia companheiros

Fiz um script para integrar o telegram ao zabbix e encaminhar os incidentes.

O Problema, o script so executa no prompt usando #python telegram.py

Porem quando executo #./telegram ele me da erro, abaixo transcrevo o script e logo após a saida da execução

---

## ! /usr/bin/python2

import telebot,sys

BOT_TOKEN='665333824:AAHTWQAz6dkS1bjpp9REu6RN-YHl_4cnTmU'
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]

MESSAGE = MESSAGE.replace('/n','\n')

tb = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

### tb.send_message(DESTINATION,SUBJECT +'\n' + MESSAGE)

---

> ```
> xxx@zabbix:./telegram
> ./telegram: line 7: import: comando não encontrado
> ./telegram: line 14: erro de sintaxe próximo do `token' não esperado `('
> ./telegram: line 14: `MESSAGE = MESSAGE.replace('/n','\n')'
> ```

---

Pelo que estou vendo ele acha que é um bash e não um python, como faço pára que ele entenda que é um python?

Agradeço a colaboração e bom dia..

Comment: Basicamente que vc precisa é ver a primeira linha do seu script: `#! caminhoounomedoexecutavel` - vide links de referência acima

Comment: Bem, a questão não é essa, pois esta declarado no script , reeditei minha pergunta inserindo o script.. se puder ajudar agradeço e desmarcar como duplicada, pois a questão deve ser outra